# How to connect to SQLite from a WPF application

Tags: c#, sqlite

I tried this solution but it didn't worked. The application starts but it fails after a while. I don't know what to do, can you help me? I used the Microsoft.Sqlite.Data package to solve this, but i don't know how to use.

For some reason i cannot resolve the problem, but I need this for a school exam. It tells me that the **filename is doesnt exist**, but it exists.

```
namespace WpfApp2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqliteConnection connection;
        ObservableCollection<Orszag> dataList = new();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void letrehozButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new($"Filename=adatok.db");
            connection.Open();
            string createTableText = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orszagok(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nev VARCHAR(100), terulet INTEGER, nepesseg INTERGER, fovaros VARCHAR(100), fovarosNepesseg INTERGER)";
            SqliteCommand command = new(createTableText, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            foreach (var item in File.ReadAllLines("adatok-utf8.txt", Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
            {
                string[] parts = item.Split(';');
                string orszag = parts[0];
                int terulet = Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]);
                long nepesseg;
                if (parts[2].EndsWith('g'))
                {
                    parts[2] = parts[2].Trim('g');
                    nepesseg = Convert.ToInt64(parts[2]) * 10000;
                }
                else
                {
                    nepesseg = Convert.ToInt64(parts[2]);
                }
                string fovaros = parts[3];
                int fovarosnepesseg = Convert.ToInt32(parts[4]);
                string insertintotext = $"INSERT INTO orszagok(nev, terulet, nepesseg, fovaros, fovarosNepesseg) VALUES('{orszag}', '{terulet}', '{nepesseg}', '{fovaros}', '{fovarosnepesseg}')";
                command = new(insertintotext, connection);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }

        private void readToTable_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new($"Filename=adatok.db");
            connection.Open();
            string queryText = "SELECT * FROM orszagok";
            SqliteCommand command = new(queryText, connection);
            SqliteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            dataList = new();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
                string nev = reader.GetString(1);
                int terulet = reader.GetInt32(2);
                long nepesseg = reader.GetInt64(3);
                string fovaros = reader.GetString(4);
                int fovarosNepesseg = reader.GetInt32(5);
                Orszag newElement = new(id, nev, terulet, nepesseg, fovaros, fovarosNepesseg);
                dataList.Add(newElement);
            }
            resultTable.ItemsSource = dataList;
            reader.Close();
        }

        private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Orszag selected = resultTable.SelectedItem as Orszag;
            string deleteText = $"DELETE FROM orszagok WHERE id={selected.Id}";
            SqliteCommand command = new(deleteText, connection);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            dataList.Remove(selected);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you specify the full path for the file?

Comment: WARNING! Who is ever teaching people to build queries like this? : `$"INSERT INTO orszagok(nev, terulet, nepesseg, fovaros, fovarosNepesseg) VALUES('{orszag}', '{terulet}', '{nepesseg}', '{fovaros}', '{fovarosnepesseg}')";`  

`>>>>>` Please read [SQL Injection](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/sqlite/sqlite-injection-attacks) `<<<<<`

Answer (score 0):

Use Absolute Path: Instead of relying on the file being in the current working directory, you can specify the absolute path to the file. This ensures that the application knows exactly where to find it.

```
string filePath = @"C:\Path\To\Your\File\adatok-utf8.txt";
foreach (var item in File.ReadAllLines(filePath, Encoding.UTF8).Skip(1))
```